# Sending messages to all clients in Unity PUN (C#)

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, photon

this is a silly question but i can't figgure it out, I tried looking it out but nothing was what i was looking, so i thought that asking might be a good way.
In my game i would like a client to be able to send messages (messages not for the users, if not for the other clients to interpreted into code) to everyone in it's room:

"(User1): How many points does everyone have?"

"(User2): Hey, I got 5 points"

"(User3): Hey, I got 10 points"

"(User1): Time is over, tell me your points:"

"(User2): Hey, I got 20 points"

"(User3): Hey, I got 30 points"

"(User1): User 3 won"

Of course, this is more of a graphical example, what I want is to be able to send messages to all clients (in the room) so other clients can process tjem. I would like to know how to do it and if this is a possible trough PUN (Unity Photon Network). Or if there is other way to do this over UnityNetworking. Additionally, this would be over LAN not over the internet.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for RPC's:

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent

This allows you to call to only the master, to only clients, or to a specific player.

Before the function you put "[PunRPC]" (without the qoutes), this makes the method callable by RPC:

```
[PunRPC]
public void GetScore(int score)
{
    //Do something
}
```

The class that calls the RPC requires have a photonview attached or extend from Pohotn.PunBehaviour, and calls the function as following:

```
photonView.RPC("function", targets, arguments);
```

The "function" is the rpc as a string, in the example case it would be GetScore, the target could be either a PhotonPlayer instance, or you could use the PhotonTargets enum.

I like to create a singleton class that handles the RPC's (Remember, this only works if the class has only 1 instance):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RPC : Photon.PunBehaviour
{
    public static RPC singleton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(singleton != null && singleton != this)
            Destroy(this);
        singleton = this;
    }

    //Called by someone who wants to set the score
    public void CallSetScore(sbyte score)
    {
        this.photonView.RPC("SetScore", PhotonTargets.All, score);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void SetScore(sbyte score)
    {
        //Do something with the score
    }
}
```

Comment: I've further explained my previous answer, why the downvote?